# I Need to integrate Surveys (any) with Codeigniter. Any one have any ideas or suggestion?

Tags: codeigniter

I Need to integrate Surveys (any) with Codeigniter. Any one have any ideas or suggestion?

Comment: What kind of surveys? Do you need to **implement** surveys? or *integrate*? I'm confused.

Comment: I've added a comment below, but I think you should perhaps be a bit more descriptive as to what you are trying to do. I and everyone else can only guess. Help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

Generally surveys are just pieces of embeddable Javascript code aren't they? Why can't you just place the code in the top of your view file in between the  tags or in your header view file if it's separate?

I presume when you say surveys you're most likely talking about CPAlead for providing them, right? Just embed it in the header.